# Powershell output PSCustomObject blocks output hashtable

Tags: powershell

I'm writing Powershell (v5.1) trying to ouptut a PSCustomObject, and then a few lines later output a hashtable. However it appears that outputting the PSCustomObject is preventing the Hashtable from outputting properly. Why does this happen?

This is a minimal example:

```
$foobar = [PSCustomObject]@{foo = 'bar'}
Write-Output $foobar # Comment out this line and it outputs wizwam

$wizwam = @{'wiz' = 'wam' }
Write-Output $wizwam
```

This is the output:

```
foo
---
bar
```

But I would have expected this output:

```
foo
---
bar

Name                           Value
----                           -----
wiz                            wam
```

Interestingly, if I comment out the second line (`Write-Output $foobar`), then it does output WizWam properly:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
wiz                            wam
```

Also, if I swap the order of foobar and wizwam:

```
$wizwam = @{'wiz' = 'wam' }
Write-Output $wizwam

$foobar = [PSCustomObject]@{foo = 'bar'}
Write-Output $foobar
```

Then it outputs both wizwam and foobar as expected:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
wiz                            wam

foo : bar
```

What is going on?

Comment: If it's exclusive for display output, you will need to add a pipe to `Out-Host` or `Out-Default` to both calls of `Write-Output`

Comment: Probably has to do how PowerShell parses the script, so piping to `Out-Default` should ensure it get's output.